# Libraries for redux database synchronization?

Tags: reactjs, redux

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979766/is-there-a-way-to-sync-local-redux-store-with-remote-data) is the only information I have found about libraries that synchronize (redux in my case) local state with backend databases. All libraries that I have found there have 0-10 downloads / month.

Do people use in practice some redux libraries for local state-database synchroniziation, or is just better to implement somethinh manually like [described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470280/how-to-keep-the-react-state-in-sync-with-mysql-database) here or like this:

```
export default function SomeReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.CONTEN_UPDATED:
            
            // Update database
            // ...

            // Update State
            return {...state, libraryBooks: action.payload.libraryBooks}
    
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you have no strong need to introduce a separate synchronization layer it is better to do it in an old fashioned way. There is more to this problem than meets the eye.

It is not a good enough proposal in your particular case (as far as I understand you have lots fo redux), but GraphQL libs are the best choice to implement synch layer. For example:

https://relay.dev/

Answer (score 1):

Reducers should be pure. That means no side effects.

Executing network requests to a backend service is obviously a side effect.
Instead, you can implement [async actions](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions) that will execute this synchronisation with your backend, and then will update the state accordingly.